# Sharepoint 2013 sends desktop version of site when viewed on Mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile, mobile-view

Let me break it down:

- I have build custom branded master pages in SP 2013, where the s4-body uses boostrap columns.
- The custom navigation is responsive, as well as the body.
- When testing on Chrome developer everything collapses perfectly, hamburger nav kicks in < 768 pixels per Boostrap CSS
- Mobile is DISABLED (as this shows libraries on the root default.aspx page.

When I view on mobile it shows an onerous 'desktop' version of the site (pinch and expand) AND the font displayed changes. Everything else appears per usual as it does on a larger resolution laptop.

Is this a SP config thing? I have media queries all set, and can't think of anything else that would prevent it from acting the way it should as resolution gets smaller.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Everything checked in and published like masterpage, CSS , page layouts ?